# MSMQ Transport Error

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

When trying to send a message with "Transport" security, i'm getting the following error:

> An error occurred while sending to the queue: No internal Message
>   Queuing certificate exists for the user. (-1072824273,
>   0xc00e002f).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are
>   sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required
>   access mode and authorization.

My config uses Transport security:

```
<binding name="MSMQBinding" ..>
   <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

Do I actually need to install a certificate?  I thought that was only for Certificate level security...

Comment: are you using public queues?

Comment: I'm using Private queues

Comment: Sounds like maybe the service that interacts with the queue does not have permissions to it. If you open up the Queue administrator, check to see if the account used for your app pool (if hosting in IIS) or your service account (if in a Windows service) has rights to the queue.

Comment: @Brian any luck on this?  I'm getting the same error message.